# Unable to get InvokedItemContainer working with Android

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

I've got a NavigationView like this:

```
<NavigationView 
        Name="NavView" 
        PaneTitle="Games" 
        PaneDisplayMode="Auto" 
        ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind games}">
        <NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Game">
                <NavigationViewItem Tag="{x:Bind id, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{x:Bind GameName}" Icon="Play"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.MenuItemTemplate>
        <Frame Name="ContentFrame" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
    </NavigationView>
```

The UI part and the binding works, but the InvokedItemContainer/ItemInvoked don't seem to work on Android. Here is the method:

```
private void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
        string id = args.InvokedItemContainer.Tag.ToString();
        Guid guid = new Guid(id);
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Leaderboard), guid);
}
```

Clicking on the `NavigationViewItem` does nothing on Android, but works fine on UWP. I've done some testing and it turns out, anything I put after the `InvokedItemContainer` statement is getting ignored, so I can only debug in UWP, where everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue with uno.ui where using a `NavigationItem` in `DataTemplate` for `MenuItemTemplate` will cause the `InvokedItemContainer` to be null.

As a workaround, you can access the data-context directly via the `InvokedItem` instead:

```cs
if (args.InvokedItem is Game game)
{
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Leaderboard), game.id);
}
```